# Why did Hermione say, "Oh shut up" in this scene?

Tags: harry-potter

On a bed scene from *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* (2009), Ron holding Hermione's hand.

> Ginny: About time, don't you think?
>
> *Pomfrey lefts a cup of tea near the bed and left*:
>
> Harry Potter: Thank you.
>
> Hermione (turns to Harry Potter): **"Oh shut up"**.

Comment: Because she wants him to shut up.

Comment: @Valorum I think you should have given this comment as an answer.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - I was sore tempted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because she strongly suspects that Harry is about to make a snarky remark about her and Ron being deeply madly in love, which, as we all know, is ***mortifyingly embarrassing*** for teens.

> **GINNY:** ‘Bout time, don’t you think?
>
> [Harry watches her go, hopelessly smitten, sees that Slughorn has
> paused in the doorway.]
>
> **SLUGHORN:** I’ve always cherished my students. They’re my life...
>
> [Then he is gone too. **Harry turns back, studies Hermione, hand
> enfolded over Ron’s. She looks up, sees his faint smile**.]
>
> **HERMIONE:** *Oh shut up*
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince: Screenplay](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:butrNfqCRKsJ:www.cinefile.biz/script/potter6.pdf%20&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)</sup></sub>